# Cannot open multiple times lightning component content as subtab in Lightning Console with different params by using workspaceAPI.openSubtab

Tags: lightning, console, workspaceapi

I want to open multiple subtabs with lightning component content in lightning Console with different parameters. Each time I call openSubtab, a new subtab should open event if there is already a subtab opened with parameters from another record.

But with my code, event if the "state" parameters changes, if there is a subtab with the same lightning component opened, the existing subtab get focused

here is my code, please help me

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
            workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(enclosingTabId) {
                workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                    parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
                    pageReference: {
                        "type": "standard__component",
                        "attributes": {
                            "componentName": "c__WZ_OrderHeader_Lightning"
                        },
                        "state": {
                            "uid": "1",
                            "c__name": component.get("v.recordId"),
                            "caseId" : component.get("v.recordId"),//case id
                            "orderId" : createQuoteResponse.orderId,
                            "accountId" : createQuoteResponse.accountId,
                            "priceBookId": createQuoteResponse.priceBookId,
                            "clientObj": createQuoteResponse.clientJSON,
                            "contactObj": createQuoteResponse.contactJSON
                        },
                    },
                    recordId:createQuoteResponse.orderId,
                    focus:true
                }).then(function(subtabId) {
                    workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                        tabId: subtabId,
                        label: createQuoteResponse.standardOrder.Name
                    });

                    // the subtab has been created, use the Id to set the icon
                    workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                        tabId: subtabId, 
                        icon: "standard:orders",
                        iconAlt: createQuoteResponse.standardOrder.Name
                    }); 
                    workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId : subtabId});                        
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("error");
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `uid` parameter from your pageReference state.

Source:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_open_pagereference.htm

> You can use the uid parameter to conditionally dedupe tabs and
>   subtabs. Omit the uid to open a new tab or subtab every time.